# What to Call IT things when they are out of order?

Tags: word-request, informal-language

can anyone please let me know? What to Call IT things when they are out of order ? for example Xbox, computer, laptop etc.

Comment: Do you mean *hardware*?

Comment: Yes , please ...

Comment: There is no difference between computer hardware and other things - what does your dictionary tell you?

Comment: For software, _b0rked._ For hardware, _bricked._ Those are my defaults, at least. ( @Stephie - Actually, there is a real difference, and there is a special jargon in play.)

Comment: Usually "broken" is used, "my Xbox is broken". "Bricked" has a more specific meaning in terms of how *something* became not useable.

Comment: @Stephie - That comment ("What does your dictionary say?") is getting a little overused around here. It's not exactly easy to find hypernyms in dictionaries – what would you look up?

Comment: @Peter, Bricked means rendered **irrevocably** unusable. http://www.howtogeek.com/126665/htg-explains-what-does-bricking-a-device-mean/

Comment: @JavaLatte If a phone is dropped in water (or smashed) it no longer works, but it is not "bricked".  "Bricking" usually involves some sort of change to the software of the phone which then renders it irreversibly useless e.g. hacking the firmware. In either case the phone is unusable.  The OP did not specify how the phone was rendered "out of order".

Answer (score 1):

We might be talking about an application running on a device, talking about the device itself or talking about some large system running on many machines (eg. an airline's checkin system, running on many terminals.)

Informally we (and I include IT professionals here) may use terms such as **broken** for any of these. However, when we need to be more specific we need to indicate the kind of problem we are seeing.

For Software we can have issues such as a sudden failures while we are using it. The word **crash** is sometimes used for such failures. We can also have incorrect behaviour while we use the software, these are **bugs** or **defects**.

For devices themselves **broken** is quite appropriate, but we would probably need to describe the kind of problem for example whether we are seeing a complete failure to power up, or the display is unreadable, or the storage system reports errors. The special case of **bricked** is quite common for portable devices. It implies that, perhaps for security reasons, the device can no longer be started, and this condition **cannot** be fixed. The device is now no more use than a **brick**.

When talking about a large computer system we might say **The system is down at the moment**. This implies that no matter which terminal we attempt to use we will not be able to use the system.

Comment: Wow that is a great piece of information. Thank you @djna it will help me in a professional email as an accountant.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but I think it could be expanded. (I'm thinking about terms like _on the fritz_ or _acting up_.)